# Given a random variable $X$ with expectation of $X^2$ and $|X|$, how can I limit the probability of $|X| >$ something？

Tags: probability

Given that $E(X^2)=1$, $E(|X|)=a$ ($a>0$), how can I prove that $P(|X|≥ λa)≥ [(1-λ)a]^2$ for all $λ∈(0,1)$?
I tried to use the Chebyshev inequality to prove $P(λa≤|X|≤(2-λ)a)≥ [(1-λ)a]^2$ but I failed.
So how to prove it by other ways?
Thank you!